# How to make simple grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I want to make a simple grid with `for` loop so that the code below will create a 5 (row) * 4 (column) grids.

```js
 for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
 let div = document.createElement('div')
 document.body.appendChild(div)
 div.textContent = i
 }
```

```css
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
text-align:center;
border:2px solid red
display:grid;
 grid-column-gap: 50px;
 grid-row-gap: 50px;
}
```

I have check some documentation before asking this question, but I still don't know how to create grid using for loop so that the item will follow the format I want.

I want the grid to display every 4 in a row and the left to display in the next row.

Output should look like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20
```

Anyone, please help me! Sorry I am bad at Javascript.

Comment: I this case it’s the body that is the grid and the divs you are creating get put into that grid so you need to style the body with display grid, not the individual items.

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks for the advise! but how could I do that. Please help me. I never deal with grid before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the body (the parent of the divs) which you want to be displayed as a grid.

So set the grid styling on body not the individual items.

Also you can tell it how may items you want in a row (ie how many columns) using grid-template-columns. In this case as you have fixed the width of each item you just want it to use the items' widths. If you wanted it to fill the available space, the width of the parent, then you'd use 1fr instead of auto.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  div.textContent = i
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @A Haworth

```
body { display:grid;
 grid-column-gap: 50px;
 grid-row-gap: 50px;
}
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
text-align:center;
border:2px solid red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5 * 4; i++) {
            let div = document.createElement('div')
            document.body.appendChild(div)
            div.textContent = i
        }
```

```css
div {
            width: 25%;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
        }
```